Sybase IQ - JDBC batch load - @p0 column not found issue
There is a solution here: PreparedStatement Does Not Work For Sybase IQ In Java
Setting LITERAL_PARAMS to true to fix the issue. However performance is really poor.
This seems like a bug with the JDBC driver, is there a fix for this?
Here’s a sample code:
PreparedStatement ps = conn.PreparedStatement(“insert into TBL(A,B) values (?,?)”);

ps.setString(1, “aa”);
ps.setString(2, “bb”);
ps.addBatch();
ps.executeBatch();

